# Loopback: How to access a model from a script?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am using Loopback and want to persist data to the database through a script.

I have written a custom command which I will be running through a cronjob:

```
'use strict';

var loopback = require('loopback');
var app = module.exports = loopback();
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

app.start = function() {
  return app.listen(function() {
    const baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    let Dish = app.models.dish;
    console.log(Dish);
  })
}

boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  if (require.main === module)
    app.start();
});
```

The output I get is:

```
Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
undefined
```

How do I access the dish model?

Comment: Please check the model case issue. you are assigning model in lower case. try `let Dish = app.models.Dish;`

Comment: I double checked, Dish is spelled lowercase in the model configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the boot function

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-boot

> The loopback-boot module initializes (bootstraps) a LoopBack
> application. Specifically, it:
>
> Configures data-sources.
>
> Defines custom models Configures models and attaches models to data-sources.
>
> Configures application settings
>
> Runs additional boot scripts, so you can put custom setup code in multiple small files instead of in the main application file.

Your server js likely contains something similar to this

```
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

app.start = function() {
    return app.listen(function() {
        const baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
        console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
        if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
            const explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
            console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
        }
    })
}

boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  if (require.main === module)
    app.start();
});
```

You need these to init the app.  You might be able to get away with only calling boot, but I think `app.start` is the one which gets your datasources connected.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work. See my updated script and output. Its still undefined though the model does exist.

Comment: What is your directory structure, is your model included in your `model-config.json`?

Comment: yes im using the default directory structure. therefor model-config.json is located in /server.

Comment: The only other thing i can think of is that this model isn't in your `model-config.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Build your command script like this:

```js
let app = require('./server/server') // Set the path according on the location of your command script

app.models.YOUR_MODEL // Access the model
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access your models in loopback as below:

First of all require server.js file in your current file.

```
const app = require('YOUR_SERVERJS_FILE_PATH');
const MY_MODEL = app.models.YOUR_MODEL_NAME
```

Here, **YOUR_MODEL_NAME** will be as same as in name value of YOUR_MODEL.json file.

Hope you will get my point.
Thank you.

Comment: The above will only work in Loopback2. But in Loopback3 you need to call the boot sequence to connect the models to the app.

Comment: Might be, not sure about it